# Can I install Phusion passenger with LAMP?

Tags: debian

Is it possible to use both PHP and Ruby on Rails side by side? I want to develop a Ruby on Rails app while using a WordPress blog. If so, does anyone have any good guides? I saw guides for setting up Phusion Passenger with Debian Squeeze, but I wasn't sure would that run side by side with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just configure `mod_php` or `FastCGI` as always in a virtual host and you are set.

Passenger is even easier to set up: `a2enmod passenger` and set your virtual host's `DocumentRoot` to `$PROJECT/public`.

They don't interfere with each other at all.